# QGIS 2D Raster Area Calculation

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a set of point cloud data in QGIS. After triangulating them and forming a Raster temporary file, i would like to find the 2D surface area of this file. IS there any tool to do it? Or do i need to use meshing methods for the point cloud file?

Answer (score 1):

You can polygonize the raster and calculate the resulted polygon's area by field calculator. Just create the field and go to its field calculator and type: `$area`.